# Cambiar propiedades del PolyLine de Google Maps - 'setStartCap' y 'setEndCap' - girar y color

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps

Estoy trabajando con Polylines en google maps.

La cuestion es que quiero agregar flechas sobre la linea que se crea. Pero investigando encontre las propiedades de **setStartCap** y **setEndCap**, las cuales me permiten insertar una imagen al inicio o al final de la Polyline.

Con esto mi problema comienza, debido a que ya he logrado insertar las flechas que deseo, sin embargo no se como cambiar el color y rotacion de la imagen.
El codigo original es el siguiente:

```
mPolyline.setEndCap(
    new CustomCap(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow),
            16));
```

con esta linea de codigo consigo insertar una flecha al final de mi Polyline, pero aun falta agregarle el color y la rotacion (Para que tenga sentido la flecha).

Investigando un poco logre hacer que rotara:

```
//Arrow
    Bitmap bmpOriginal = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.right_arrow_button);
    Bitmap bmResult = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpOriginal.getWidth(), bmpOriginal.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(bmResult);
    tempCanvas.rotate(260, bmpOriginal.getWidth()/2, bmpOriginal.getHeight()/2);
    tempCanvas.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0, 0, null);



    mPolyLine.setEndCap(new CustomCap(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmResult),8));
```

Con el codigo anterior, ya se cambia la posicion de la flecha, pero no puedo cambiar el color de esta. Ademas de que no se si sea lo mas optimo.

Mi pregunta es, como puedo lograr que la imagen sea 'girada' segun un angulo y como puedo cambiar el color de esta, de la manera mas optima posible?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

no me queda claro para que desearias rotar una polyline, pero aca te dejo como cambiarle de color.

```
mPolyline.color(Color.GREEN);
```

Comment: y como puede  lograr que la imagen sea 'girada' segun un angulo ?